# Не запускается logstash

Tags: java, logstash

Установил logstash по инструкции с оф сайта под windows https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/libbeat/5.6/logstash-installation.html

При запуске пишет, что нет main класса.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В гугле везде примерно такая же инструкция,  не понятно в чем проблема, может быть я что то недокачал или logstash требуется ставить поверх elasticsearch

Comment: я не в теме, но, судя по скрину, проблема у вас в том, что путь ваш содержит пробел `D:\Program{пробел}Files\....`. Попробуйте запустить то же самое из другой папки, без пробела, или попрвить конфиги так, чтобы пути были в кавычках.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема у вас в том, что путь ваш содержит пробел

```
D:\Program{пробел}Files\.....
```

Попробуйте запустить то же самое из другой папки, без пробела, или поправить конфиги так, чтобы пути были в кавычках.